# Button set to visibility Gone is still clickable

Tags: android, android-button

In my activity I have a switch, which when checked creates an animation and a button appears on the screen. When the switch disabled the button disappears also with an animation. When the button disappears I set the visibility to gone and when it appears I set the visibility to visible.
The initial state of the button is gone and when I try to click the location it supposed to be nothing happens. When the buttons appears it becomes clickable. If I make it disappear again, it's still clickable. Why is that? I thought that setting visibility to gone prevents the button from being triggered. I know I can set the button to `setEnabled(false)`, but I'm curious why the button is still clickable when I set it visibility to gone.

Here's my `onCreate()`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        show = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.show);
        hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.hide);
        ((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.animation_switch)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).startAnimation(show);
                            ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                      
                        }
                    }, 3000);

                }else{
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).startAnimation(hide);
                            ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).setVisibility(View.GONE);                             
                        }
                    },3000);
                }
            }
        });

        ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Here is the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Animataion"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/animation_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notification_switch" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/animated_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:text="click me"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the show animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
    android:duration="450"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    />
</set>
```

Here's the hide animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    />
</set>
```

Comment: it is still there after view.gone?

Comment: @HappySingh no, it disappears, but if I click the area where it supposed to be, I get the toast message.

Comment: I had added my answer.

Comment: Try to use an if statement inside the onClick to check the visibility of your button eg -: if ( yourButton.isShown() ). See if this works.

Answer (score 4):

If you set setVisibility(View.GONE) after the animation, then try clearing the animation on your views with clearAnimation() at the end of the animation

```
mview.clearAnimation()
```

**OR**

this can also work while initializing your animation because there are some bugs with animations.

```
show = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.show);
hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.hide);
show.setFillAfter(false);
hide.setFillAfter(false);
```

Comment: I tried using `mview.clearAnimation()`, but it just disabled it. The button appeared and disappeared without animation. `setFillAfter(false)` however did the trick, but what is the difference between doing that and `setEnabled(false)`?

Comment: I am not sure about it. but animation overlays the screen while animation. as method name showing setFillAfter(false) . it's take caring for space which given to it.

Comment: The documentation says "If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished."

Comment: and for the setEnabled document "Set the enabled state of this view."

Comment: You should put clearAnimation() in .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {} which has method of OnAnimationEnd

Comment: mView.clearAnimation() worked for me. Thanks -@HappySingh

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.hide);
hide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.animated_button)).setEnabled(false); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
```